# Provide a std::istream interface to an existing buffer without copying it

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a buffer of chars of a fixed length and I'd like to feed it to a function that takes a std::istream&. How can I do that without copying the buffer?

If it means deriving a custom streambuf, I think I'll live with the copy. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something straightforward.

Here's what I'm doing now (which does the unwanted copy):

```
void loadFromBuffer(const char* buff, size_t len) {
    std::istringstream is(std::string(buff, len)); // BUFFER COPIED HERE :(
    load(is);
}
```

**Edit:**

For the record, here's the straightforward solution using [boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

void loadFromBuffer2(char* buff, size_t len) {
    typedef boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> array_stream;
    array_stream is(buff, len);
    load(is);
}
```

I accepted the Boost.Iostreams answer because it seems to be the "right" solution, however it doesn't compile on my platform (Android NDK), so I ended up using the deprecated std::istrstream solution. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Did you check the copy was not optimized away in this case ?

Comment: Just for your information, `std::istrstream` provides this functionality.
It has the constructor `(char*, streamsize)`.
However, as you may know, this class is deprecated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been in a similar situation myself, and instead of creating everything myself I used [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/index.html), creating a read-only source device.

Untested, but this may work:

```
class ConstBufferDevice
{
public:
   typedef char char_type;

   struct category :
      virtual boost::iostreams::device_tag,
      virtual boost::iostreams::input_seekable
   {
   };

   ConstBufferDevice(const char_type* buffer, size_t buffersize)
      : buffer_(buffer)
      , buffersize_(buffersize)
      , pos_(0)
   {
   }

   std::streamsize read(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize buffersize)
   {
      const std::streamsize amount = static_cast<std::streamsize>(buffersize_ - pos_);
      const std::streamsize result = (std::min)(buffersize, amount);
      if (result != 0)
      {
         std::copy(buffer_ + pos_, buffer_ + pos_ + result, buffer);
         pos_ += result;
         return result;
      }
      else
      {
         return buffersize ? -1 : 0; // EOF
      }
   }

   std::streampos seek(boost::iostreams::stream_offset offset,
                       std::ios_base::seekdir seekdir)
   {
      // Determine new value of pos_
      boost::iostreams::stream_offset newpos;

      if (seekdir == std::ios_base::beg)
      {
         newpos = offset;
      }
      else if (seekdir == std::ios_base::cur)
      {
         newpos = pos_ + offset;
      }
      else if (seekdir == std::ios_base::end)
      {
         newpos = buffersize_ + offset;
      }
      else
      {
         throw std::ios_base::failure("bad seek direction");
      }

      // Check for errors
      if (newpos < 0 || newpos > buffersize_)
      {
         throw std::ios_base::failure("bad seek offset");
      }

      pos_ = static_cast<size_t>(newpos);
      return boost::iostreams::offset_to_position(newpos);
   }

private:
   const char_type* buffer_;
   size_t buffersize_;
   size_t pos_;
};

typedef boost::iostreams::stream<ConstBufferDevice> ConstBufferStream;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As for the code, doesn't the library provide this functionality already? I was looking at [boost::iostreams::array_source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) and on a quick skim of the docs it looks like it does the same thing. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Martin Stone: The only thing my solution gives you that `array_source` doesn't is that my solution is seekable. If you don't need that, go with `array_source`.

Comment: @dalle Is there a way to return a pointer to internal buffer_ ? (special cases for me) How about to find out the effective(written) data available in buffer ?

Comment: @dalle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919330/iostream-expose-memoryinputstream-buffer-and-its-size

Comment: @dalle There is a strange behavior when I use this (and also boost ibufferstream) because I don't get EOF when ConstBufferDevice returns -1(EOF)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to provide a custom implementation of `std::streambuf` that references an external (rather than internal) buffer.  Once you have this, you could subclass off of `std::istream` and provide a constructor that sets up the `istream`'s stream buffer to be an instance of your custom `streambuf` type that points to your buffer.  This immediately gives you the full capabilities of an `istream` that would be backed by your external buffer.  IIRC, most of the complexity of implementing `streambuf` involves the complexities of refilling the buffer when it runs out of data, but in your case that should be trivial since you can just report that you're out of data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP said he doesn't want to subclass std::streambuf.

Comment: @dark_charlie: I'm pretty sure this can't be done without subclassing `streambuf`.  The main point of this answer is that I don't think it would be as difficult as it may initially seem.

Comment: Ok. Still, a copy is a lot easier and if the buffer isn't big the performance issues will be negligible.

Comment: I think it's possible without subclassing. See my solutionn. Let me know if it's wrong!

Comment: Note that the use of [Boost.Iostreams](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) makes implementing your own stream-buffer *much* simpler.

Comment: Seems to be the concept for me: Have a function reading from an istream. As there is no virtual read(), streambuffer is the only option to intercept.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible. The STL containers/streams etc. always want to own the buffer, thus they copy it. There's no simple way I am aware of.